Periodic stripe artifacts in rendered depth maps with Blender4.1
I am using Blender to render a synthesized stereo dataset with depth maps. The code I use to save the depth is:
    for side in ["left", "right"]:
        bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects[f"camera_{side}"]
        for i in range(FRAMECNT):
            bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i+1)
            bpy.ops.render.render()
            depth = np.asarray(bpy.data.images["Viewer Node"].pixels)
            depth = np.reshape(depth, (H, W))
            #depth = depth[:, :, 0]
            depth = np.flipud(depth)
            np.save(path + f"depth_{side}/%06d.npy" % i, depth)

The compositing graph is:

However, the depth maps I get have strange periodic stripe artifacts. I see the image with:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
depth = np.load("000001.npy")
plt.imshow(depth)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

The result looks like this.

A close up look:

I guess this is a problem with data format conversion or something else, but I have no idea how to figure it out. I also suspect that the bpy.data.images["Viewer Node"] step has some problem, but when I use bpy.data.images["Depth"], there is an error "Key not found".
Thank you for any help!

You could set up nodes to render to an intermediate, like EXR, then load that with opencv and save it in whatever numpy batches you need, right?

@Leander Thank you very much, this solved the problem!

@Leander, HY Lou ... and looks like a worthwhile answer, if one of you has a moment.. Any clue about the origin of the artefact?

@RobinBetts I don't have any idea what the exact problem is, but (I also suspect that the bpy.data.images["Viewer Node"] step has some problem) doing ops.render into grabing the viewer node data is much too hacky for me to start investigating. The viewer node workaround is to strange for these applications (e.g. doesn't even work in background mode).

@RobinBetts I think it has something to do with the "Resolution Scale". When I first tried the output-to-EXR solution, I noticed that I got 240320 images (the resolution I set was 480640), and the depth images were strange (there was a lot of noise on it). Then I found the 50% resolution scale setting, and turned it off. Then everything went well.
